# How can I prove propositional extensionality in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove a substitution theorem about Prop, and I'm failing miserably. Can the following theorem be proven in coq, and if not, why not.

```
  Theorem prop_subst:
    forall (f : Prop -> Prop) (P Q : Prop), 
      (P <-> Q) -> ((f P) <-> (f Q)).
```

The point is that the proof, in logic, would be by induction. Prop isn't defined inductively, as far as I can see. How would such a theorem be proven in Coq?

Comment: I don't think you can prove that, but I don't know the details...

Comment: I could add it as an axiom, but that would be kind of vulgar, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MayerGoldberg sorry, read your question too quickly ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Here's the answer: The property I was looking for is called *propositional extensionality*, and means that `forall p q : Prop, (p <-> q) -> (p = q)`. The converse, is trivial. This is something that is defined in `Library Coq.Logic.ClassicalFacts`, together with other facts from classical, i.e., non-intuitionistic logic. The above definition is called `prop_extensionality`, and can be used as follows: `Axiom EquivThenEqual: prop_extensionality`. Now you can apply the `EquivThenEqual`, use it for rewriting, etc. Thanks to Kristopher Micinski for pointing towards extensionality.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it ;-), I was just about to point you to the section in the FAQ

Comment: When your own answer is the most fitting, you can help me learn Coq by marking your answer as accepted. You'll get the reputation points. Don't be bashful--Stack Overflow is intended to work like that.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called "*extensionality*:"

http://coq.inria.fr/V8.1/faq.html#htoc41

http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality

EDIT:

You can admit *predicate* extensionality, as noted in the Coq FAQ.

Comment: I don't think this is extensionality: Notice that I'm using only one function (which serves as a context), and not two, as with extensionality. What I want is called referential transparency: If A <-> B, then I should be able to substitute B for A in any expression than any expression that contains A. On the other hand, perhaps you meant "propositional extensionality", which isn't the same, but seems to give me what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This is propositional extentionality.

```
Lemma blah: forall (P Q: Prop), (forall (f:Prop -> Prop), f Q -> f P) -> P = Q.
  intros P Q H.
  apply (H (fun x => x = Q)).
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Section S.

Hypothesis prop_subst:
  forall (f : Prop -> Prop) (P Q : Prop), 
    (P <-> Q) -> ((f P) <-> (f Q)).

Lemma prop_subst_is_ext: forall P Q, (P <-> Q) -> P = Q.
  intros.
  apply blah.
  intro f.
  destruct (prop_subst f P Q); assumption.
Qed.

End S.

Check prop_subst_is_ext.
```