# (A <-> B) -> A = B?

Tags: coq

Suppose I define this set.

```
Inductive Set_1 : Set :=
  | Constr_1 : Set_1
  | Constr_2 : Set_1.
```

Is it possible to prove this statement?

```
(Constr_1 = Constr_2) = False
```

If so, what tactics do I use? This might be useful for `autorewrite`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can this be proved in coq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071165/how-can-this-be-proved-in-coq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(A <-> B) -> A = B` is called propositional extensionality and is implied by [classical logic](http://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ClassicalFacts.html).

But you don't need it for using equivalences with `autorewrite`, just `Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid`.